# Create unordered list in render array

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I'm attempting to create an unordered list using a render array in a custom block in a custom module.

I understand if I wanted to wrap things in div I could always use the 'container' type. Like so

```
    $content = [
        'container'    => [
            '#type'       => 'container',
            '#attributes' => [
                'class'      => ['container'],
            ],
            'item 1'      => [
                '#type'       => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'        => 'p',
                '#value'      => 'Item 1',
            ],
            'item 2'      => [
                '#type'       => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'        => 'p',
                '#value'      => 'Item 2',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

But I'd like to be able to use an unordered list like so

```
    $content = [
        'container'    => [
            '#type'       => 'html_tag',
            '#attributes' => [
                'class'      => ['container'],
            ],
            '#tag' => 'ul',
            'item 1'      => [
                '#type'       => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'        => 'li',
                '#value'      => 'Item 1',
            ],
            'item 2'      => [
                '#type'       => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'        => 'li',
                '#value'      => 'Item 2',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

What I'd like that to produce is

```
<ul class="container">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

But instead it produces

```
<ul class="container"></ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
```

Is there a way to create an unordered list using render arrays?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the theme 'item_list':

```
$content = [
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#list_type' => 'ul',
  '#title' => 'My List',
  '#items' => ['item 1', 'item 2'],
  '#attributes' => ['class' => 'mylist'],
  '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => 'container'],
];
```

The wrapper_attributes are not used in all themes. In core this is `classy` and `bartik`, which is based on classy.

Comment: Would you point me to the documentation for this?

Comment: I think the best documentation is in the template: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/system/templates/item-list.html.twig

Comment: You should replace '#list_type' with '#type' according to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7.x

Comment: @rudolfbyker, this is a D7 link, but how is #list_type (a template variable of item_list) and #type (specifies a render element) connected?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the "8" tag on the question. What I meant to say is this: The code in the answer works for D7 only if you change `#list_type` to `#type`. `#list_type` is ignored.