# Adding cache tags to custom block

Tags: blocks, 9, caching

I have a **custom block** which load some taxonomy terms.

When I made changes to my taxonomies, the block isn't loading the new data (due to the cache). I'm passing all my taxonomy tags to my `#cache return`, but nothing append when I reload my page. I still have to `drush cr` to see the changes (even tried with `taxonomy_term_list`, but didn't work either)

Here's a simplified version of my block :

```
<?php

**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "custom_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("custom block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Custom")
 * )
 */
class CustomBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

    // properties ...
    // constructor...
    // create() ...

    public function build() {
        // ...
        $tags = generate_tags_by_id($terms, self::CACHE_TAXONOMY);
        // ['taxonomy_term:34', 'taxonomy_term:40' ... ]
        return [
            /// ...
            '#cache' => [
                // 'tags' => //$tags,
                'tags' => ['taxonomy_term_list'],
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Here's my container config :

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false
  twig.config:
    debug: false
    auto_reload: false
    cache: true
```

Also tried to hook on taxonomy update, launch a custom event which invalidate those caches, but not working.

I'm using drupal 9.5.7

Comment: If you set `http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true`, do you see 'taxonomy_term_list' in the response headers?

Comment: Where should I check this ? inside my block by passing *$request* in `build()` ?

Comment: In the F12-tools of your browser or command line `curl --head www.example.com`.

Comment: It's missing from the head

Comment: Then your block doesn't render #cache. This can be a problem that $build is not a render array or the block template doesn't render it correctly.

Comment: Be sure to do a full rendering (like `{{ content }}`) in your Twig template. If you do only partial rendering (like `{{ content.field_foo }}`), the cache tags will never bubble upwards and will never be included in the final page. If you can't to a full render, do something like `{% set dummy_trigger_cache = content|render %}` to trigger cache processing.

Comment: @4uk4 why woudn't it be rendered correctly ?

Comment: For example, you would put the terms in an array and loop over this array in the template, this would be a problem in the block template. Use a separate template, if you can't build this in a recursive render array.

Comment: So I have to print always `{{ content }}` as suggested @Hudri ?

Comment: Not always, but in general it's good practice to use the block template as a wrapper around content and render the inside in a custom template if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you don't build a render array and render it in the block.

If you want to theme a taxonomy term list then don't try to do this in the `block.html.twig` template. Use a custom template and put it in the block render array:

```
public function build() {
  // query $terms
  return [
    '#theme' => 'my_term_list',
    '#terms' => $terms,
    '#cache' => [
       'tags' => ['taxonomy_term_list'],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then `#cache` will be recognized containing the list cache tag necessary if you query taxonomy terms in the database. The template can then include the cache tags of the single terms while rendering them.

Alternatively you can use a core `#type` or `#theme`, for example to render the terms in list tags. See [Create unordered list in render array](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214928/create-unordered-list-in-render-array)